# Adding Dexie.js queries in JavaScript file gives hint of missing type

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, dexie

If I add a Dexie.js query in a JavaScript file such as:

```
let friends = liveQuery(async () => {
  return await db.friends
    .where("age")
    .between(18, 65)
    .toArray();
});
```

I get a hint like this:

> "Property 'friends' does not exist on type 'Dexie'.ts(2339)"

Why?

Putting it in a [Svelte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svelte) file is fine, but I would like to keep some basic queries in one place, like find, add, and delete.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: It's in vscode. Should have stated that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to a TypeScript error. If you are not subclassing Dexie as suggested on [Dexie's Svelte tutorial](https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Svelte#using-typescript), you cannot use `db.friends` directly without TypeScript complaining. If you don't want to subclass Dexie, you can also use the `table()` method:

```
let friends = liveQuery(async () => {
  return await db.table('friends')
    .where("age")
    .between(18, 65)
    .toArray();
});
```